# Arduino SoftwareSerial connections

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I'm building a pet project which consists of an Arduino (Uno, at the moment), a GPS (Sparkfun GS407) and a GSM modem (Sparkfun ADH8066). The idea is I'll be able to SMS the modem, and have it reply with where it is.

Problem is, when I have both the GPS and GSM module plugged in, serial comms start getting messy. Now I have two ideas why this is happening;

1) Apparently I need a good ground when using serial comms (only using 9600 baud). I'm new to electronics so I'm not sure how I would improve my ground.

2) I've read somewhere (probably [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial)) that SoftwareSerial only supports one set of pins sending/receiving at any one time. This could prove problematic if the GPS is spewing out spurious amounts of data, as they do.

Can anyone comment as to the reason I'm seeing odd serial output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grounding should not be an issue. As long as you have a ground connected you should be fine. The Sparkfun breakboard boards will have taken care of any sensitive grounding issues.

The odd data is almost certainly from using multiple softwareserials, which is not recommended as you have discovered.

One solution would be to use the hardware serial port for one device, and a software serial port for the other. (GPS on hardware since it updates more frequently than GSM)

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any code I might use? I'm struggling to find code which is efficient, and doesn't constantly poll the GSM modem (via serial) for new SMS messages.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to setup the softwareserial so that when the GSM modem sends a terminating character (indicating a line as been sent), the softwareserial interrupt will automatically call some function you want to call to process that update. This would eliminate you needing to do available() and read() constantly. However you will need to modify the library to do so, but it may not be that hard. There will be an interrupt service routine (ISR) coded in the library, so you can edit that and say if the byte read was a terminating character (\0, or a null terminator), run X function.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace SoftwareSerial with the much better AltSoftSerial (http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) instead.

And yes, keep one of the devices on the hardware serial port as that is superior to any serial solution implemented in software.